# Is there a place where i can download the PSVita Content Manager Installer that does not require a net connection?

Tags: ps-vita

The computer which I have all my images on and has the most space to store a few backups doesn't connect to the internet so I need to find a version of the installer which works totally offline.

Now I did find this site
(http://cma.dl.playstation.net/cma/win/gb/)
but it says:

> During the installation process, dialog boxes might appear that direct you to download components (additional software) needed to operate Content Manager Assistant for PlayStation®. If this happens, follow the on-screen instructions to download the components.

Since I can only have 1 computer connected at a time I dont want to waste time shutting down and starting up again between the two if the download is wrong, so is there a place where I can download an installer that doesn't require the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid I'm not allowed to put up a link here, but google for OpenCMA. It's a hacked version of CMA that requires no internet connection to operate. I have used it since it was first released, a few weeks after the vita release, and it works perfectly.

Edit:
I just downloaded CMA from [the official site](http://cma.dl.playstation.net/cma/win/en/index.html) and disconnected my internet. I then installed CMA using the installer I downloaded and everything went fine. It did not try to download any patches, nor did it complain about not having an internet connection.
Keep in mind though, that the official CMA needs an internet connection to copy content to and from your psVita, no matter what type of content. OpenCMA is basically an unofficial patch/hack for CMA that lets you copy content without an internet connection. So if you are going to install CMA to a computer that won't have an internet connection, you need OpenCMA as well to use the program.

Comment: i didn't know the content manger needed the net connection to run but i keep finding a patch that needs to the applied to the original install and thats my problem, the installer i found said it may need to download more components needed which will interrupt the install if im not on the net, you know where i can get an offline install of the original software....also, surprised you can't post links, stack overflow allows it and i posted up one

Comment: @Memor-X I'm not sure there is an offline installer, even OpenCMA needs the regular one to be installed. As for the link thing, I'm not sure links to OpenCMA are allowed here, as it is a hacked version of the official CMA.

Answer (score 0):

Just download QCMA - it operates in "offline" mode by default (though you can override this, if you want) and thus far, it's worked flawlessly for me!

http://psx-scene.com/forums/content/qcma-linux-content-manager-assistant-work-progress-3750/

Installation instructions can be found here (you need to install VitaMTP1 first, then QCMA):
https://github.com/xiannox/qcma/wiki/Usage#on-linux